# tex4ht + biblatex + non-ascii chars = mixed encoding in html file

Tags: biblatex, tex4ht, xhtml

I have this situation

- a LaTeX file with a macro that is usually translated into a unicode char by tex4ht (e.g. `\ldots` that became `…`)
- a citation with non-ascii char in the name of the author (e.g. the `í` in `Albarracín`)
- I would like to generate an xhtml file with htlatex

The procedure works, but the resulting file has one char encoded in utf-8 (the latex macro) and the non-ascii char in the author's name encoded in latin-1. AFAICT, htlatex includes the bbl file reading it as if it was in latin-1.

Is there anything that I could do to fix this behavior? :)
(I'm working on `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux)`)

Here is a mwe, and below the commands that I run:

```latex
%% File mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Albarracin2000,
year = {2000},
volume = {1},
issue = {2},
pages = {3},
author = {Anyone Albarracín},
title = {A beautiful paper.},
journaltitle = {Some Journal}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

I Am a Scientist\ldots\ Ask Me Anything
\parencite{Albarracin2000}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

```sh
htlatex mwe.tex "xhtml" "-cunihtf -utf8" "" ""
biber mwe
htlatex mwe.tex "xhtml" "-cunihtf -utf8" "" ""
```

and the result

```sh
$ file mwe.html
mwe.html: XML 1.0 document, Non-ISO extended-ASCII text
$ grep -a -e 'Anyone Albarra' -e Scientist --color mwe.html 
<!--l. 22--><p class="noindent" >I Am a Scientist… Ask Me Anything [<a 
    <!--l. 26--><p class="noindent" >Anyone Albarrac�n. &#8220;A beautiful paper.&#8221; In: <span
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `utf8` support is one of the issues that is solved by `make4ht`. If you compile your file using:

```
$ make4ht mwe.tex
```

It will produce `utf8` file by default.

If you want to use `htlatex`, you can use this:

```
$ htlatex mwe.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

Two significant modifications have been made. Firstly, by including `charset=utf-8` in the option list, the encoding of the HTML file has been changed, enabling browsers to display accented characters correctly. Secondly, it is crucial to separate the opening quote and `-cunihtf` with a space; otherwise, the option is ignored, resulting in a wrongly encoded file.

I still recommend to use `make4ht`, as it is easier to use, and it fixes other issues too. For example, you can create a build file, `build.lua` that will compile the bibliography on request:

```lua
if mode == "draft" then
  Make:htlatex {}
else
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:biber {}
  Make:htlatex {}
  Make:htlatex {}
end
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
$ make4ht -e build.lua mwe.tex
```

It will automatically call `biber` and then it will run LaTeX twice, to fix all cross-references. If you want to speed up the compilation, you can use the `draft` option, which will run LaTeX only once, resulting in the much faster compilation:

```
$ make4ht -e build.lua -m draft  mwe.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: A minor clarification for me to remember: I think that `charset=utf8` correctly sets the tag `<meta ... content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the html file, but the encoding of the file itself is fixed by `" -cunihtf -utf8"` (**with** the space in front) :)

Comment: @MatteoGamboz yes, that's correct. Without correct declaration in the `<meta>` tag, the text could be displayed incorrectly, even if the HTML file itself contained correct characters.